# Sales Order Grid is empty after data migration process

Tags: magento2, migration, order-grid

I've made data migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2 using data-migration-tool according to this article http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-data.html

Orders migrated successfully, but Sales Order grid is empty - this happened because `sales_flat_order_grid` (from Magento 1) and `sales_order_grid` (from Magento 2) tables are ignored in the mapping file by default, like this.

```
<destination>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
           <document>sales_order_grid</document>
        </ignore>
    </document_rules>
</destination>
```

These tables have different columns (Magento2's table has 10 additional columns), and they can't be moved just like that.

Is there any way to re-build `sales_order_grid` table, based on another tables data?

I've cleaned cache and made all reindexes, with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment out or remove line 20 to 31 in map.xml file,

```
<!-- <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_invoice_grid</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_order_grid</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>sales_flat_shipment_grid</document>
            </ignore> -->
```

Add inside `<document_rules>` tag of source tag,

```
 <rename>
            <document>sales_flat_order_grid</document>
            <to>sales_order_grid</to>
        </rename>
        <rename>
            <document>sales_flat_invoice_grid</document>
            <to>sales_invoice_grid</to>
        </rename>
        <rename>
            <document>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid</document>
            <to>sales_creditmemo_grid</to>
        </rename>
        <rename>
            <document>sales_flat_shipment_grid</document>
            <to>sales_shipment_grid</to>
        </rename>
```

Add below content under `<field_rules>` tag of source tag.

```
     <move>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.grand_total</field>
            <to>sales_creditmemo_grid.order_base_grand_total</to>
        </move>
         <!-- source table custom  grid field-->
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_invoice_grid.base_grand_total</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.store_to_order_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.base_to_order_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.store_to_base_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.base_to_global_rate</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.creditmemo_status</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.invoice_id</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.store_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.order_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.base_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_flat_creditmemo_grid.global_currency_code</field>
        </ignore>
```

comment out or remove line inside `<destination>`  `<document_rules>` tag,

```
 <!-- <ignore>
            <document>sales_creditmemo_grid</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>sales_invoice_grid</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>sales_order_grid</document>
        </ignore> 
        <ignore>
            <document>sales_shipment_grid</document>
        </ignore>-->
```

Add below line inside `<destination>` part of `<field_rules>` tag

```
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.billing_address</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.shipping_address</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.shipping_information</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.customer_email</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.customer_group</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.subtotal</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.shipping_and_handling</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.customer_name</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.payment_method</field>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <field>sales_order_grid.total_refunded</field>
        </ignore>

    <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.store_name</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.customer_name</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.customer_email</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.customer_group_id</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.payment_method</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.billing_address</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.shipping_address</field>
    </ignore>
     <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.shipping_information</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.subtotal</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_invoice_grid.shipping_and_handling</field>
    </ignore>

    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.customer_name</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.order_status</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.billing_address</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.shipping_address</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.billing_name</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.shipping_name</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.customer_email</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.customer_group_id</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.payment_method</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_shipment_grid.shipping_information</field>
    </ignore>

    <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.billing_address</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.shipping_address</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.customer_group_id</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.order_status</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.customer_name</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.customer_email</field>
    </ignore>
     <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.payment_method</field>
    </ignore>
     <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.shipping_information</field>
    </ignore>
     <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.subtotal</field>
    </ignore>
     <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.shipping_and_handling</field>
    </ignore>
     <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.adjustment_positive</field>
    </ignore>
    <ignore>
        <field>sales_creditmemo_grid.adjustment_negative</field>
    </ignore>
```

save map.xml file and 
run `php magento migrate:data /var/www/html/{{magentoroot}}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/{{CE version}}/config.xml`

Comment: I follow same things, still it not import grid data for Order, Invoice, Shipment and credit memo. And other idea for this?

Comment: Hi @rakesh please let me know why you have ignored these fields? is there any specific reason.

Comment: @rakesh I have followed your step but no luck

Comment: @rakesh can u please help on this ASAP https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291019/magento-2-order-grid-loading-issue-after-data-migration

Comment: Hello, I have one question about this. I run the migration and all things working. just orders are not working. can I run the migration again with changes as you suggested?

Comment: worked in my case. Thank you